# Java subclass with private constructor yields Compilation error

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

Can you help me understand why the following code gives compilation error?
If I remove Foo2's constructor, it works fine.

```
class Foo2 {

    int st;

    protected Foo2(int initialVal) {
        this.st = initialVal;
    }
}

public class Main extends Foo2 {

    int st;

    private Main(int initialVal) {
        this.st = initialVal;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Foo2 f = new Main(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you even have that Main constructor? why are you overriding/hiding the variables  in the class? add super(initialVal); as first line in the child constructor, see what that does

Comment: I bet the compiler-error pretty clearly states what your error is and what to do.

Comment: `Foo2` does not have a default constructor and you are not calling a super constructor in `Main`. You probably want to add `super(initialValue);` as first line in `Main`'s constructor

Comment: is there a specific reason why you have protected and private access modifiers in yours constructors?

Comment: It's a theory question that popped up . I just want to know the reason behind it

Comment: Adding to @ernest_k's comment: This has nothing to do with the constructors' visibility!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your `Main` class implicitly calls `super()`. But since your `Foo2` class has a constructor with parameters, the compiler doesn't generate for it a parameter-less constructor, so the implicit `super()` call is invalid.

You can fix this by either removing the existing `Foo2` constructor (as you did) or adding a second (parameter-less) constructor to `Foo2` or adding a `super(someIntValue);` call as the first statement of the `Main` constructor.

Here's the 3rd alternative:

```
private Main(int initialVal) {
    super(initialVal);
    this.st = initialVal;
}
```

Of course, it doesn't make sense to have the `st` instance variable in both the super class `Foo2` and the sub-class `Main`.

```
private Main(int initialVal) {
    super(initialVal);
}
```

would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the compiler will add `super()` in subclass constructor if you have not added

so in your case parent class have single parameterized constructor so it will not be callable using `super()`

so you have to call `super(initialVal)` to make it work

if you don't won't add `super(initialVal)`, then you have to create default constructor 
in parent class without paramter, so it can be callable through `super()` which will add by compiler